# Whats the difference between $(a^2+b^2+2ab)$ and $((a+b)^2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My mathematics textbook says that:

> $(a+b)^2 = a^2+b^2+2ab$

But I am stuck on the question

> If $x + \frac{1}{x} = 5$, then find the value of $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

The book solves it like this:

$    {x + 1\over x^2} = 5^2$
$    {x^2 + 1\over x^2} + 2 \cdot x \cdot {1\over x} = 25$
$    {x^2 + 1\over x^2} + 2 = 25$
$    {x^2 + 1\over x^2} = (25-2)$
$    {x^2 + 1\over x^2} = 23$

I did it like this:

$    {x + 1\over x}^2 = (5)^2$
$    {x^2 + 1\over x}^2 = (5)^2$
$    {x^4 + 1\over x^2} = 25$
$    {x^4\over x^2} + {1\over x^2} = 25$
$    x^2 + {1\over x^2} = 25$
The answer I got is $25$, while the correct answer is $23$. The answer became $23$ after the *author* subtracted $2$ from $25$.

But I never got that $2$, because it comes from $2ab$ and the formula I am using doesn't have that part.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to maths stack exchange. It would be really helpful if you could edit your equations into mathjax format-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Note that $2\cdot x \cdot \frac{1}{x}=2$

Comment: I suppose that one step is missing $\left(x+\frac 1x\right)^2=x^2+2\times x \times \frac 1x+\frac 1{x^2}=x^2+2+\frac 1{x^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x+1/x=5$ then $25=(x+1/x)^2=x^2+2+1/x^2$ so $x^2+1/x^2=23$
In your calculation there are errors from line 1 to 2, from line 2 to 3, from line 3 to 4. I think you are misplacing some parentheses and that the real error (missing the double product) is from line 2 to 3. But just my guess...

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes into light when you square $x^2+1$ in the numerator in line $2$ of your approach , which comes out to be $x^4+2x^2+1$.
Thus, when you divide the entire fraction by $x^2$, you are left with
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2,$$
Which is equal to $25$. The final answer for
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$ 
is $23$.

As far as the book's solution is concerned, I'm guessing there are quite a few typos, as I can't really understand the method.